# Sequelize update

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update a model in Sequelize using the following code:

```
exports.updateItem = function(item) {
    return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
        models.TimesheetItem.update(item,{where: {id: item.id}})
                            .then(fulfill)
                            .catch(console.dir);
     });
};
```

Where item is the result of doing models.TimeSheetItem.find()

The call never executes the .then and instead passes an empty object to the .catch.

I've looked over the documentation and it seems that this is the way to update a row, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the documentation the [`update`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows) method takes two parameters - first one is `values` which will be used to perform the update, and second one is `options` - so in your case this is the `where` clause. If you want to perform an update on a single instance only, you can do it in two ways - use `Model.update()` method, which can update multiple instances of this model at once matching the `where` clause, or perform `instance.update()` in order to update only the single instance. First option will look like that:

```
let updateValues = { name: 'changed name' };
models.Model.update(updateValues, { where: { id: 1 } }).then((result) => {
    // here your result is simply an array with number of affected rows
    console.log(result);
    // [ 1 ]
});
```

The first option is not very useful when you want to update only single instance. So that is why there is a possibility of performing `update()` on Sequelize model instance

```
let updateValues = { name: 'changed name' };
instance.update(updateValues).then((self) => {
    // here self is your instance, but updated
});
```

---

In your case, if the `item` parameter is a Sequelize model instance (not a plain javascript JSON object), your update function could be like that

```
exports.updateItem = function(item){
    return item.update(values).then((self) => {
        return self;
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

However, if the `item` is not a sequelize model instance but only a plain object with values you want to update, it could be done in two ways - first is to use `Model.update()` (just like you did), or second one is to retrieve `TimesheetItem` with `id = item.id` and then perform `instance.update()` as shown above

```
exports.updateItem = function(item){
    models.TimesheetItem.update(item, { where: { id: item.id } }).then((result) => {
        // here result will be [ 1 ], if the id column is unique in your table
        // the problem is that you can't return updated instance, you would have to retrieve it from database once again
        return result;
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

Or the second option with returning instance and performing update on it

```
exports.updateItem = function(item) {
    return models.TimesheetItem.findById(item.id).then((itemInstance) => {
        return itemIstance.update(item).then((self) => {
            return self;
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

The difference is that you do not need to create and return your own `Promise` - sequelize methods like `update()` return promises by themselves.

Comment: Wonderful answer, you explained it perfectly.
Many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
{ error: type "where" does not exist}
```

Just an update to the solution, Sequelize now gives the  error above when you include the 'where' option(as shown below). So take it out and it should work perfectly.

```
exports.updateItem = function(item){
    models.TimesheetItem.update(item, { id: item.id  }).then((result) => {
        // here result will be [ 1 ], if the id column is unique in your table
        // the problem is that you can't return updated instance, you would have to retrieve it from database once again
        return result;
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

Comment: you didn't add the where clause `{ where: { id: args.id } }`, you only added `{ id: args.id }`